# python registration doesnt work rightly

Tags: python, django

i can't do a registration process Works look, here is my code

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    Usuario = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
    Cargo_Contacto = models.CharField("Cargo del cliente",max_length=50,null=True)
    Celular = models.PositiveIntegerField("Numero de celular",null=True)
    Pagina_web = models.URLField("Pagina Web",blank=True)
    Numero_de_identificacion = models.PositiveIntegerField("Numero de identificacion",null=True)
    Nombre_Empresa = models.CharField("Nombre de la empresa",max_length=50,null=True)
    Telefono = models.PositiveIntegerField("Numero de telefono",null=True)
    Extension_Telefono = models.PositiveIntegerField("Extension del telefono",null=True)
    GeneroEscoger = ((1,"Sin especificar"),(2,'Masculino'),(3,'Femenino'))
    Genero = models.IntegerField(choices=GeneroEscoger, default=1)
    Ciudades = ( (1,'Bogotá'),(2,'Medellin'),(3,'Cali'),(4,'Barranquilla'),(5,'Cartagena'),(6,'Cucuta'),(7,'Ibagué'),(8,'Bucaramanga'),(9,'Otro'))
    Ciudad = models.IntegerField('Ciudad',choices=Ciudades, default=1,)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cliente'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clientes'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Usuario.username
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, Estado=False)
    usuarios = UserProfile.objects.filter(Usuario=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistroUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # En caso de ser valido, obtenemos los datos del formulario.
            # form.cleaned_data obtiene los datos limpios y los pone en un
            # diccionario con pares clave/valor, donde clave es el nombre del campo
            # del formulario y el valor es el valor si existe.
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            username = cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = cleaned_data.get('password')
            email = cleaned_data.get('email')
            # E instanciamos un objeto User, con el username y password
            user_model = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            # Añadimos el email
            user_model.email = email
            # Y guardamos el objeto, esto guardara los datos en la db.
            user_model.save()
            # Ahora, creamos un objeto UserProfile, aunque no haya incluido
            # una imagen, ya quedara la referencia creada en la db.
            user_profile = UserProfile()
            # Al campo user le asignamos el objeto user_model
            user_profile.user = user_model
            # Por ultimo, guardamos tambien el objeto UserProfile
            user_profile.save()
    else:
        # Si el mthod es GET, instanciamos un objeto RegistroUserForm vacio
        form = RegistroUserForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'notifi': notifi,
        'usuarios': usuarios
    }

    return render(request,'app/index.html',context)
```

**registrations.html**

```
<form method="post" action="."  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class RegistroUserForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(min_length=5,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=5,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(min_length=5,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def clean_username(self):
        """Comprueba que no exista un username igual en la db"""
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.filter(username=username):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Nombre de usuario ya registrado.')
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        """Comprueba que no exista un email igual en la db"""
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Este E-mail ya se encuentra registrado.')
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        """Comprueba que password y password2 sean iguales."""
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Las contraseñas no coinciden.')
        return password2
```

some times work, but when work, don't relog page with session log, then i wish if i need add something or i have to say the user login, and why sometimes doesn't work registration?, just relog the page and no sabe the information

Comment: Parcero... Could you show the RegistroUserForm code?

Comment: @JoseRomero ok, se me olvido agregarlo